# Does aws s3 sync s3://mybucket s3://mybucket2 copy files to local?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to copy a (large) s3 bucket to another s3 bucket as part of my deploy process.  Does running `aws s3 sync s3://mybucket s3://mybucket2` copy the files in mybucket to the local machine where this command is being run? Or do the files stay serverside?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this command, files (or objects) are being synchronized between two S3 buckets across AWS network and do not get copied to your local machine during the process.

Comment: Additionally, it's worth mentioning that the buckets can also be in different regions. You issue the command to the **destination region**, which then copies the files from the source region.

Comment: Add a reference to documentation where it says files are not copied to local machine. It adds value to your answer. Without that your answer is just an opinion.