# AWS S3 sync command from one bucket to another

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, synchronization

I want to use the AWS S3 sync command to sync a large bucket with another bucket.
I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41252423/does-aws-s3-sync-s3-mybucket-s3-mybucket2-copy-files-to-local) answer that say that the files from the bucket synced over the AWS backbone and are not copied to the local machine but I can't find a reference anywhere in the documentation. Does anyone has a proof for this behavior? any formal documentation that explains how it works?

I tried to find something in the documentation but nothing there.

Comment: This post will help you about which network used. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63821830/5589820

Comment: The S3 CLI command's `cp` and `sync` will fall back to using [CopyObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_CopyObject.html) and [UploadPartCopy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_UploadPartCopy.html) when appropriate.  These APIs don't take data, only references to existing data and they cause S3 to copy data internally.  I'm not aware if this is formally documented, but it can be verified with the `--debug` command line option showing which APIs are called.

Answer (score -2):

To learn more about the sync command, check [CLI docs](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/s3/sync.html). You can directly refer to the section named -

> **Sync from S3 bucket to another S3 bucket**
>
> The following sync command syncs objects to a specified bucket and
> prefix from objects in another specified bucket and prefix by copying
> s3 objects. An s3 object will require copying if one of the following
> conditions is true:
>
> - The s3 object does not exist in the specified bucket and prefix
>   destination.
> - The sizes of the two s3 objects differ.
> - The last modified time of the source is newer than the last modified time of the destination.

Use the S3 replication capability if you only want to replicate the data that moves from bucket1 to bucket2.

Comment: Can you please proof-read your answer? It doesn’t really make much sense right now.

Comment: made changes to make it more understandable

Comment: chatgpt answer, if you dont know dont respond

Comment: THis is not chatgpt anser. If you go through mentioned cli doc, you will come to know how sync command works between 2 buckets. Do read the refered link